# Correct way to fetch data when switching route on same level in react-router?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

What is the correct way to fetch data when switching route on same level?
Because, according to [this](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/blob/master/docs/guides/ComponentLifecycle.md), switching route on same level will
only call `componentWillReceiveProps` and `componentDidUpdate`.
And `componentDidMount` is only called the first time route is entered.

With route configuration like this:

```
render((
  <Provider store={store}>
    <Router>
      <Route path="/" component={App}>
        <Route path="/:userId" component={Profile}/>
      </Route>
    </Router>
  </Provider>
), document.getElementById('root'));
```

The Profile component is:

```
class Profile extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    // initial data
    this.fetchUserData();
  }
  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if (this.props.params.userId !== nextProps.params.userId) {
      this.fetchUserData();
    }
  }
  shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps) {
    return this.props.params.userId !== nextProps.params.userId;
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="profile"></div>
    );
  }
}
```

The data will be stored in application state field (`props.userData`). But,
that's obviously will mess up with rendering cycle because route is
switched before fetch data is finished.

But, if I change to this:

```
// deepEqual is function to check object equality recursively
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
  if (!deepEqual(this.props.userData, nextProps.userData)) {
    this.fetchUserData();
  }
}
shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps) {
  return !deepEqual(this.props.userData, nextProps.userData);
}
```

This won't work because before `userData` is fetched, those props is
deeply equal.

So, how to fetch data when switching route on same route level?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Component does not remount when route parameters change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32261441/component-does-not-remount-when-route-parameters-change)

Comment: Sigh ...
And almost three years later, this question is marked as duplicate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [React Router docs](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/blob/dd22bbe1a74246d13ebcb821e7711a83ff950115/docs/guides/ComponentLifecycle.md#fetching-data):

```
componentDidMount () {
  // fetch data initially in scenario 2 from above
  this.fetchInvoice()
},

componentDidUpdate (prevProps) {
  // respond to parameter change in scenario 3
  let oldId = prevProps.params.invoiceId
  let newId = this.props.params.invoiceId
  if (newId !== oldId)
    this.fetchInvoice()
},
```

When route changes `this.props.params.userId` will update, which is caught in componentDidUpdate, and fires off a fetch. Of course this fetch will likely update state or props firing another re-render to show the fetched data.