# React, redux component does not update on route change

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router, react-redux

I have the route /zone/:id, when clicking from /zone/123 to /zone/789, I can successfully dispatch an action to get the new state, however the component does not render to display the new data.

I tried [adding in a key](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39150493/6784431) to the `<Link/>` that is clicked to change routes to trigger an update but that did not work.

Followed the [troubleshooting guide](http://redux.js.org/docs/Troubleshooting.html) for react-redux and think I may be mutating the state in some way?

Maybe I'm trying to change routes in the wrong way?

I hook into the ComponentWillReceiveProps and check to see if the params.id has changed and if it has I issue the fetchZone action to retrieve the new zone.

**Zone.js**

```
class Zone extends Component{
  constructor(){
    super()

    this.state = {
      zone: {}
    }
  }

  componentDidMount(){
    this.props.fetchZone(this.props.params.id)
  }

  componentDidUpdate(prevProps){
    if (prevProps.zone !== this.props.zone){
      this.setState({zone: this.props.zone})
    }  
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps){
    if(nextProps.params.id !== this.props.params.id){
      this.props.fetchZone(nextProps.params.id)
    }
  }

 render(){
   ...
 }

 function mapStateToProps(state){
  return {
      zone: state.zones.zone,
      coordinates: state.zones.coordinates
    }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, {fetchZone, getCoordinates})(Zone)
```

[Using react-logger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oii85.png) shows that the state does return the new zone, but does not update the component.

**Reducer**

```
case FETCH_ZONE:
  return { ...state, zone: action.payload.data.result}
```

**Root Reducer**

```
const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  zones: ZonesReducer,
  form: formReducer
});
```

So props and redux state along with component state will update, yet the component does not re-render with new zone data being displayed.

Answer (score 1):

```
import {withRouter} from 'react-router-dom'
```

and then

```
withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps, {fetchZone, getCoordinates})(Zone))
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add `setState()` in `componentWillReceiveProps`.

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps){
    if(nextProps.params.id !== this.props.params.id){
      this.props.fetchZone(nextProps.params.id);
      this.setState(...) // setState here
    }
  }
```

And [here](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#componentwillreceiveprops) is the document.

Comment: Isn't it bad convention to use setState while using Redux? I think Redux should handle all of state. Correct me if I misunderstood.

Comment: @Kunok http://redux.js.org/docs/faq/OrganizingState.html#organizing-state-only-redux-state You could check this FAQ

Comment: Oh I see , that makes sense!

Comment: When I `setState` in `componentWillReceiveProps` it still doesn't update the component. 


I added `if (nextProps.zone !== this.props.zone){
      this.setState({ zone: nextProps.zone})
    }`