# React Router V3 - Nested Route Component unmounts on path param change

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I just noticed that in react router (v3.x) a component unmounts and remounts if a path param changes. Is this the expected behaviour?

Route:

```
<Route path="/landing/register/:step" component={Register}/>
```

Now, lets say I am on route `"/landing/register/personal-data"` and I am navigating via `<Link/>` or `router.push({...})` to the next registration step `"/landing/register/address"`, the Register-component gets first unmounted and then mounted again, loosing all its state.

Is this the correct way or am I doing something wrong?

**EDIT:**

It seems that the problem is that I am using nested routes, where I use a component for the parent route.

This example works (not re-mounting Register-Comp on path param change):

```
<Route path="/landing">
   <Route path="register/:step" component={Register}></Route>
</Route>
```

But when I use a component for the parent route, it doesnt (not re-mounting AppView-Comp, but Register-Comp on path param change):

```
<Route path="/landing" component={AppView}>
   <Route path="register/:step" component={Register}></Route>
</Route>
```

Comment: You might want to change [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32261441/component-does-not-remount-when-route-parameters-change) to understand how component unmount/remount on URL params change

Comment: I think this lead me to the correct path (see my edited question). The parent component `AppView` receives new props, and is triggering a re-render, leading to re-mounting the child components. I think I have to store the state elsewere, or do a check in `shouldComponentUpdate`

Answer (score 0):

I solve this problem by nesting routes in child components, like this:

```
// Router class
 <Route path="/landing/register" component={Register}/>


 //Register component

 <BrowserRouter>
  <div> 
   <Route path="/landing/register/personal-data" component={PersonalData}/>
   <Route path="/landing/register/payment-data" component={PaymentData}/>
   ...other routes
  </div>
 </BrowserRouter>
```

But in this case i store user data in redux store instead of component state, however you can store it on your component state it is not problem.

Comment: OP uses v3 and not version 4