# React router v4 with redux not able to re-render component

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-router, react-router-v4

I am having a difficulties with rendering the components when the new location is being pushed.

using these versions:

> ```
> "react": "^16.5.2",
> "react-router-dom": "^4.3.1",
> "redux": "^4.0.0"
> ```

**Base.js**

```
<div >
    <Header />
    <div id="contentwrapper">
        <BrowserRouter>
            <Switch>
                <Route exact path='/' component={Home} />
                <Route path='/service/details/:id' render={(props) => (
                            <ServiceDetails key={props.match.params.id} {...props} />)
                        } />
            </Switch>
        </BrowserRouter>
    </div>
    <Footer id="footer" />
</div>
```

**How I am pushing the location:**

The location is being pushed from `<Header>` component where the `connect` is wrapped with `withRouter` from `react-router-dom`: (`export default withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Header));`)

```
var route = "/service/details/" + value        
this.props.history.push(route)
```

**Child component (ServiceDetails.js)**

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';
import _ from 'lodash';

import { getServiceDetailsAction } from '../actions/ServiceActions';
import { getServiceDetails } from '../requests/ServiceAxios';

class ServiceDetails extends React.Component {

    // constructor

    componentWillReceiveProps(newProps) {
       debugger;
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                Service details: {this.props.location.pathname.substring(this.props.location.pathname.lastIndexOf('/') + 1)}
            </div>
        )
    }
}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
        serviceStore: state.ServiceReducer
    };
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
    return bindActionCreators({
        getServiceDetailsAction: getServiceDetailsAction
    }, dispatch);
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(ServiceDetails);
```

The link is updated correctly in the url bar of browser but the component is not rendered. Also the `componentWillReceiveProps` of the child component is called only once when the whole app is loading.

Current behavior:

- this.props.history.push("/service/details/5")
- page renders `Service details: 5`
- this.props.history.push("/service/details/262")
- page still shows `Service details: 5`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Component does not remount when route parameters change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32261441/component-does-not-remount-when-route-parameters-change)

Comment: edited my question

Comment: can you create Sandbox example? https://codesandbox.io/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Header Component is out of the Router Provider Component, Wrap your Header within the `BrowserRouter` component

```
<BrowserRouter>
    <div >
        <Header />
        <div id="contentwrapper">
           <Switch>
               <Route exact path='/' component={Home} />
               <Route path='/service/details/:id' render={(props) => (
                                <ServiceDetails key={props.match.params.id} {...props} />)
                            } />
           </Switch>
        </div>
        <Footer id="footer" />
    </div>

</BrowserRouter>
```