# How to remount a componet on Route change using react-router-dom instead of re-rendering

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4, react-router-dom

**UPDATE: How this question differs from the duplicate?**

**Here we have the same component being rendered by 2 different routes.** In the other question, OP wants to know how to re-mount a component being rendered by the same single route over and over, just by changing the route params.

Link: [Component does not remount when route parameters change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32261441/component-does-not-remount-when-route-parameters-change)

---

I have the following situation on a `ProductSearch`  component.

It might be rendered by two different `<Route>'s`:

They both display `ProductSearch` page with filters to corresponding products.

```
<Route exact path='/category/:slug' component={ProductSearchContainer}/>
<Route exact path='/search/:slug' component={ProductSearchContainer}/>
```

**The 1st one happens when you click on a product category menu:**

- So the results are already inside a specific category.
- Then it displays filters that are specific for that product category.

**The 2nd one happens when you search products using the `SearchBar` with some text.**

- You're not inside a category yet, so it only displays generic filters like `Price`, `Brand`, `Rating`, etc...

The problem is that if you change straight from one route to the other, **the component will simply re-render. And I would it like better for it to remount**, because then I would get a fresh start on my selected filters active state and productList, etc...

**For example, this would happen in the following scenario:**

1. The user clicks on category nav button `Phones`
2. The `ProductSearch` component gets rendered for the `Phones` category
3. The user filters a bunch of stuff and decides to do a text search and start from scratch
4. The user searches for `some random text`
5. The `ProductSearch` gets re-rendered (with the 2nd route) **but all the filtered states will remain the same if I don't reset them.**

Note the URL change in the GIF below:

[image]

**QUESTION:**

Is there a way to make sure my component will get remounted if it changes to a different route in this case?

**Example on CodeSandbox:**

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-routerremountonroutechangeso-881m3

---

**Full Code: index.js**

(in case the CodeSandbox link is not available anymore)

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Link, Switch, Route } from "react-router-dom";

import "./styles.css";

function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <AllRoutes />
    </Router>
  );
}

function AllRoutes(props) {
  return (
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
      <Route exact path="/category/:slug" component={ProductSearch} />
      <Route exact path="/search/:slug" component={ProductSearch} />
    </Switch>
  );
}

function Home(props) {
  return (
    <div>
      <div>I am Home</div>
      <div>
        <Link to="/category/phones">Phones</Link>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

function ProductSearch(props) {
  console.log("Rendering ProductSearch...");

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("ProductSearch mounted...");
    return () => console.log("ProductSearch unmounted...");
  }, []);

  // useEffect(() => {
  //   console.log('Inside useEffect for slug...');
  //   console.log(props.match.params.slug);
  // },[props.match.params.slug]);

  return (
    <div>
      <div>I am ProductSearch</div>
      <div>
        <Link to="/">Home</Link>
      </div>
      <div>
        <Link to="/search/phoneModelXYZ">Search for Phone XYZ</Link>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Component does not remount when route parameters change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32261441/component-does-not-remount-when-route-parameters-change) - one of the answers there shows a way to force re-mount, the others explain why it's better not to.

Answer (score 1):

So here's what I've ended up doing:

By giving a key to the rendered component in the Route you can make it re-mount instead of re-render.

```
<Route exact path='/category/:slug' render={(routeProps)=>
  <ProductSearch {...routeProps} key={routeProps.match.params.slug}/>}
/>
<Route exact path='/search/:slug' render={(routeProps)=>
  <ProductSearch {...routeProps} key={'search'}/>}
/>
```

Now I get the following result:

[image]