# Update Redux state on route change

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router-redux

I've been trying to figure this out for a while and I'm getting more and more confused.

I want to reset/change Redux state every time I leave or change route. I'm using `react-router-redux` with `history.listener` dispatching an action every time route changes

```
history.listen(location => store.dispatch(resetManualsCategory()));
```

---

Action creator:

```
export function resetManualsCategory() {
    return {
        type: 'RESET_MANUALS_CATEGORY'
    }
}
```

---

Reducer

```
export function manualCategories(state=[], action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'SELECT_MANUALS_CATEGORY':
           [...]

        case 'RESET_MANUALS_CATEGORY':
            console.log('test reducer');
            return Object.assign({}, state, {
                manualCategory: 'test'
            })

        default:
            return state
    }
}
```

What confuses me the most, the state updates if I refresh the page or click twice on the route in the top nav, but a single route change doesn't affect the redux state even though the action and reducer fire (displays the test message in the console).

What am I doing wrong and what actually is happening here?

Answer (score 21):

`react-router-redux` provides a `LOCATION_CHANGE` action, which is already dispatched on every route change. You could do simple:

```js
import { LOCATION_CHANGE } from 'react-router-redux'

export function manualCategories(state=[], action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case LOCATION_CHANGE:
            /*
              action.payload is something like:
              {
                pathname: '/',
                search: '',
                hash: '',
                state: null,
                action: 'PUSH',
                key: 'xwl8yl',
                query: {},
                $searchBase: {
                  search: '',
                  searchBase: ''
                }
              }
            */

        default:
            return state
    }
}
```

Comment: is ``LOCATION_CHANGE`` the same as ``@@router/LOCATION_CHANGE``?

Comment: Yes. You could also use '@@router/LOCATION_CHANGE', but it's not recommended.

Comment: I just realised what's causing the problem and it's slightly different from this question. Maybe you could help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37912180/react-router-redux-takes-two-clicks-on-a-link-to-update-location-state

Comment: Is this applicable as well if you want to reset the state of only a specific route only?

Comment: This answer doesn't work anymore. react-router-redux has been renamed to connected-react-router, and it doesn't look like it works the same way anymore.

Comment: Also does not work on router v6

Answer (score 8):

I used different approach for resetting the state when changing routes. Instead of listening to history/ router, I used `componentWillMount` event on my page containers to dispatch a "reset page" action.
Example:

Router:

```
<Provider store={store}>
  <Router history={history}>
    <Route path="/page1" component={Page1Container} />
    <Route path="/page2" component={Page2Container} />
  </Router>
</Provider>
```

Page1 container:

```
class Page1Container extends Component {

  componentWillMount() {
    this.props.resetPage()
  }

  render() {
    // render Page1
  } 
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    // ...
  }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    // ...
    resetPage: () => { dispatch({type: 'PAGE1_RESET_PAGE'}) }
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Page1Container)
```

Reducer:

```
const initialState = null

export function Page1Reducer (state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'PAGE1_RESET_PAGE': {
      state = initialState
      break
    }

    // ...
  }
}
```

---

**Update**:
As @DavidHarkness mentioned, the flaw of this approach is that the component will render twice on mounting. 
And apart from that, I now tend to think that this solution is not elegant and it is better to avoid using bussiness logic inside components.
Moving the logic inside the reducer would be a better option (see @DiegoHaz answer).

Comment: This seems like it would be a good solution if for some reason you only need to reset the part(s) of state the component used.

Comment: Won't this render with the previous state and then immediately render again with the new state?

Answer (score 3):

Currently I'm making use of [componentWillUnmount()](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentwillunmount) to do this. I have an action setup in the reducer I want to reset to reset its state and I dispatch the action from the **componentWillUnmount()** method.

One issue you may experience with this is that when using React Router a  route change will not trigger a refresh and a component will not remount on the same route, so for example if you have a posts/new and a posts/edit/:id route both using the same component to edit a post, going between these routes will not cause the component to remount.

Because of this **componentWillUnmount()** will **NOT** run, the same component will just receive new props. Therefore you could use **componentWillReceiveProps(newProps)** to perform a comparrison and update accordingly.

If you do want to force the component to remount you need to ensure the component you want to remount has a different key attribute, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32261441/component-does-not-remount-when-route-parameters-change) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31813512/is-it-possible-to-only-remount-only-the-new-child-components-on-react-router-tra#answer-31816415) for more information.