# React-router-redux takes two clicks on a Link to update location state

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome-devtools, redux, react-router-redux

I have an issue with my app that I cannot find solution for anywhere. I use `react-router-redux` and `syncHistoryWithStore`.

When I click on my navigation to change a route using Link the new route loads, URL in the browser updates, however the `location` state doesn't update unless I click the Link two times.

UPDATE:
I've noticed it might have something to do with Chrome React DevTools. If I open the React Devtools and select provider then unwrap the components tree one at a time, the `location` state updates and everything works fine. However, if I use the search bar to locate the target component, `location` state doesn't work any more and the app breaks. Weird?!

Has anyone encountered a similar issue before? Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: are you returning false in any click handlers for your links conditionally? like if something is not setup correctly? aka if the url hasn't changed you could be killing the propagation to not update state before the url actually changes. Not really sure without seeing code though

Comment: I'm having the same issue. The url changes, but it takes another click on the link for the location to actually change.