# How to clear redux state once the user visit another route?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router, state, redux-toolkit

I have the following problem: I have a general component that contains some data from the redux store and I want to clear this data once the user visits another route.

```
<Route path="/create/gallery" element={<CreatePage type={ContentType.gallery}/>} />
```

also I have some more code that saves my entered data to the store

```
saveGeneralInfo = (field: string, value: string) => {
        const data = {};
        data[field] = value;
        this.props.dispatch(saveGeneralInfo(data));
}
```

How I can clear the state if the user leave the page or visit any other link? (For example from header)

```
if(this.state.keycloak) {
   if(this.state.authenticated) return (
      <div className="App">
           <Header/>
            <Routes>
                <Route path="/" element={<Content />} />
                <Route path="/sites"/>
                <Route path="/users"/>
                <Route path="/create/gallery" element={<CreatePage type={ContentType.gallery}/>}/>
                <Route path="/create/article" element={<CreatePage type={ContentType.article} />} />
                <Route path="/create/quiz" element={<CreatePage type={ContentType.quiz} />} />
             </Routes>
      </div>
                );
                else return (
                    <div>Can't authorize</div>
                )
            }
```

Comment: react-router-redux provides a LOCATION_CHANGE action. Similar problem described here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37911075/update-redux-state-on-route-change

Comment: What have you tried already? What isn't working? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

You will have to provide functionality for store clearing that fires on `unMount` lifecycle event in every route root component.

If you are using functional components:

```
export const Component = () => {

const dispatch = useDispatch();

useEffect(() => {
  return () => {
    dispatch(yourActionThatCleansReduxStore())
  }
}, [])

//rest of your code
}
```

In my case I reset parts of my store for every page URL like `/info` or `/user` where store looks like

```
{
  user: {
   id: ...
  },
  info: ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a route controller using children component

```
import { useDispatch } from "react-redux";
import { useLocation } from "react-router-dom";
import { cleanState } from "Your-reducer.js";    

function CleanState({ children }) {
  const location = useLocation();
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(cleanState()); // every time the route changes clean the state
    // if you don't use redux-toolkit you can use action.payload etc....
  },[location.pathname])

  return <>{children}</>;
}

export default CleanState;
```

then you have to wrap the main component

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import YourComponents from "./YourComponents"; // Your components
import CleanState from "./CleanState"; // where did you save it

function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <CleanState> // This is the previous component, this will listen the movements of the routes
         <Routes>
           <Route path="/main" element={<YourComponents />} />
           <Route path="*" element={<YourComponents />} />
         </Routes>
      </CleanState>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```